# io.quarkus DEBUG logs do not appear but all other debug logs appear

Tags: logging, quarkus

DEBUG logs from `io.quarkus` package not appearing on console.

I want to view DEBUG/TRACE logs from `io.quarkus` package (to check token validation steps and more details.) but I do not seem to get these logs.
These logs appear on console when I run `mvn quarkus:dev` but they do not appear when I run the code as JAR.

Below is my `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.log.level=TRACE
quarkus.log.console.enable=true
quarkus.log.console.format="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c] %s%e%n"
quarkus.log.console.level=TRACE
```

All debugs from my own packages or from other packages like hibernate, netty appear just fine.

I tried setting min-log level, removing console related configurations but no luck.